# handsontable decimalplaces (with it's numeric.js)

Tags: jquery, numeric, numerical, handsontable

**Solved**, It's a known bug, see below!

Thought to implement handsontable for various spreadsheet like duties. but I'm stuck on the decimal places, when altering the cells.

http://handsontable.com/demo/numeric.html (doesn't work in my implementation, nor in the example. at least consistent :)

If you change values in the decimal places they eventually add positions in front of the dot or comma (either $ or EU).

**Edit1** i.e. if you change the 7000 for mercedes to 7000.01 it actually makes it 700001(.00)

**Edit2** Getting even more precise. Not working on FF21, chrome27, nor IE8 (company nb...)

Does anybody have a clue?

Comment: I'm not fully clear on what is happening. Could you give an example of i.e. what you change and what happens? Also, are you using latest version of handsontable? My implementation of the same example is working.

Comment: if you change the 7000 for mercedes to 7000.01 it actually makes it 700001(.00)

Comment: Thanks. Yes, that is strange behavior and I can see the online example is somewhat 'buggy' too. When I run locally, without the "language" property or with "language: 'en'", then everything works fine. If I set language to 'de-de' then I get a runtime error in the handsontable js. Do you need language as de?

Comment: Yep, DE is needed. I will massively play around with currencies. Maybe I have to work that out and contribute. Thanks again (As mentioned below).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, it appears you have come across a know issue/bug, still open, with the current version.

See these issues:

https://github.com/warpech/jquery-handsontable/issues/751

https://github.com/warpech/jquery-handsontable/issues/464

Try removing the language option if you don't need 'de-de' as this seems to work for me. Otherwise, you could possibly try your own custom column renderer, or similar, as a workaround.

Comment: found the bug right now in parallel. thanks for your investigation.